# break out of the while loop?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, break

How can i break out this while loop?  i want it to break it out when i type "finish." But it dose not seems to work.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        PlayerReader r = new PlayerReader();
        PlayerWrite w = new PlayerWrite();
        r.Check();

        System.out.println("Welcome, Please type enter or type finish to store information");

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        String str = sc.nextLine();
        String cond = "finish";

        while(str != cond)
        {

            w.writeName();
            w.writeScore();
            if(str == cond)
            {
                System.out.println("Information stored");
                sc.close();
                break;
            }

        }


    }


}
```

Comment: Re-read the `String` in the loop. And don't compare `String` with `==` (that's reference equality).

Comment: just use if(str.equals(cond)) it will solve your problem.

Comment: and please refer this for better understanding of string comparision.              http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: use if(str.equals(cond)){} instead. You are actually checking references of both the string and not the values they hold.